# No route was found matching the URL In Woocommerce Product variations request?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

during product variation request, it gives an error "No route was found matching the URL and request method" How to resolve it? thanks in advance.

Comment: What was the request you made?

Comment: wc-api/v3/products/1341/variations

Comment: now its working thanks God i have trying to last night, just added on provider class   wpAPI: true, version: "wc/v2" below of consumer secret key now it working.

Comment: Great, to hear that